# input_shape issue in Neural networks with Keras in Python

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, keras

I am trying to replicate exactly [this tutorial](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/julienr/ipynb_playground/blob/master/keras/convmnist/keras_cnn_mnist.ipynb) on neural networks using the MNIST data set. When I just copy-paste it into my Python editor, I get the following exception:

```
Exception: The first layer in a Sequential model must get an `input_shape` or `batch_input_shape` argument.
```

So I tried to specify the input sheme using

```
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 1, 3, 3, border_mode='same', input_sheme=(1,28,28)))
```

but I guess I did this wrong.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typo

```
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 1, 3, 3, border_mode='same', input_sheme=(1,28,28)))
                                                                 ^
```

should be

```
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 1, 3, 3, border_mode='same', input_shape=(1,28,28)))
```

Answer (score 1):

It says so right there

> Exception: The first layer in a Sequential model must get an `input_shape` or `batch_input_shape` argument.

I will now try to break this error message up for you. Next time you try it yourself.

> The first layer in a Sequential model [...]

A sequential model is a model that uses a sequence of layers to generate an output from an input. I venture a guess that the `Convolution2D` layer is actually the first layer in your model.

> [...] must get an `input_shape` or `batch_input_shape` argument.

Keras has to know which shape the input has. So you have to supply it to the first layer or use an `Input` layer with that shape. You are supplying the `input_sheme` parameter, which this layer does not even have. Try supplying `input_shape` instead. For MNIST this is usually `(784,)` because that's the number of pixels a 28 by 28 image has.